# How to guarantee checker runs after monitor each timestep

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, test-bench

I have several agents each with their own monitor and analysis ports connected to a checker. The checker is organized like below where it calls each check() function every cycle in a specific order. This is done this way to handle the case where we get an input and output txn in the same cycle (design has "bypass" logic to immediately output the txn it sees on its input in the same cycle).

If we go with design #2 (below), there is no guarantee that we will process the input_txn first, so if we happen to process the output_txn first, the assertion could fire because it doesn't know that there was an input_txn in the same cycle. I have had success using Design #1 to handle the case where we get an input and output txn in the same cycle; however I now realize this is still not guaranteed to work correctly because it's possible that the simulator could execute the checker's run_phase() after the output_agent's run_phase() but before the input_agent's run_phase(), and I could get the same issue.

What I really want is almost a "check_phase" for each timestep, so I can guarantee all agents monitors' have finished executing in the current timestep before the checker starts executing. Is there any way to guarantee the checker executes after all other processes in the current timestep?

P.S. I'm not looking for advice on how to improve my checker, this is just a very dumbed down version of my actual testbench I made to easily convey the problem I have.

```
## Design 1 ##
class my_checker extends uvm_component;
  //boiler plate uvm...
  task run_phase();
    forever begin
      check_inputs();
      check_outputs();
      @(posedge vinft.clk);
    end
  endtask

  function check_inputs();
    input_txn_c txn;
    if (input_analysis_fifo.try_get(txn)) begin // non-blocking try_get()
      //do check
      pending_txn_cnt++;
    end
  endfunction

  function check_outputs();
    output_txn_c txn;
    if (output_analysis_fifo.try_get(txn)) begin //non-blocking try_get()
      assert(pending_txn_cnt > 0);
      pending_txn_cnt--;
    end
  endfunction
endclass


## Design 2 ##
class my_checker extends uvm_component;
  //boiler plate uvm...
  task run_phase();
    fork
      check_inputs();
      check_outputs();
    join_none
  endtask

  task check_inputs();
    input_txn_c txn;
    forever begin
      input_analysis_fifo.get(txn); //blocking get()
      //do check
      pending_txn_cnt++;
    end
  endtask

  task check_outputs();
    output_txn_c txn;
    forever begin
      output_analysis_fifo.get(txn); //blocking get
      assert(pending_txn_cnt > 0);
      pending_txn_cnt--;
    end
  endtask
endclass
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a FIFO for both the input and output, you should be able to use this simple design:

```
class my_checker extends uvm_component;
    //boiler plate uvm...
    input_txn_c  txni;
    output_txn_c txno;

    task run_phase();
        forever begin
            // Wait until there is an input transaction: txni
            input_analysis_fifo.get(txni);

            // Wait until there is an output transaction: txno
            output_analysis_fifo.get(txno);

            // Now there is a pair of transactions to compare: txni vs. txno
            // call compare function...
        end
    endtask

    // compare function...
endclass
```

Since the `get` calls are blocking, you just need to wait until you have an input transaction, then wait until you have an output transaction.  It does not matter if they arrive in the same timestep.  Once you have an in/out pair, you can call your compare function.

I don't think you need to check the transaction count for every pair.  If you want, you could check if the FIFO's still have anything in them at the end of the test.